# Can I configure eclipse to expand packages with the right arrow in ubuntu?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I recently switched from windows to ubuntu, and this is bothering me. I used to be able to expand packages by pressing the right arrow, but now I have to press `enter` to do it in ubuntu.

Is there any way to change that?
(I've never touched any configuration regarding this, that's why I assume it has to do with the operating system)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a similar question on stack overflow, I found out how to [configure arrow keys to work on Eclipse's package explorer on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747264/is-it-possible-to-use-arrow-keys-alone-to-expand-tree-node-in-package-explorer-i). In short:

Put this into your `~/.gtkrc-2.0` and you should be good to go.

```
binding "gtk-binding-tree-view" {
    bind "Left"     { "expand-collapse-cursor-row" (0,0,0) }
    bind "Right"    { "expand-collapse-cursor-row" (0,1,0) }
}
class "GtkTreeView" binding "gtk-binding-tree-view"
```

Update: You may have to restart eclipse.